# Set "Start In" directory for a shortcut using batch commands

Tags: shortcuts, batch-file

I've created the following shortcut for my software using a batch file.

```
set target_file_a=\\%server_name%\program.exe
@echo off
set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"
echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\shortcut.lnk" >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.TargetPath =  "%target_file_a%" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%
cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%
```

I need to set the "Start In" directory. How can I do this in batch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`WorkingDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae0a4aee(v=vs.84).aspx) member. In your case:

```
echo oLink.WorkingDirectory = "something" >> %SCRIPT%
```